# Python pygame - bouncing ball (UnboundLocalError: local variable 'move_y' referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, pygame

I wanted to create a function that is responsible for bouncing ball from the edge of the screen. I know i can do it better with math and Vector2 function but i wonder why i have this error, and why i can run window without this line of code:

```py
if ball.y >= HEIGHT - 10:
    move_y = -vall_vel
```

Code

```py
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, window):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y), 10)

ball = Ball(WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2, red)

def main():
    run = True

    ball_vel = 10
    move_x = ball_vel
    move_y = ball_vel

    def update():
        WINDOW.fill(black)

        ball.draw(WINDOW)

        player.draw(WINDOW)
        pygame.display.update()

    def ball_move():
        
        if HEIGHT - 10 > ball.y > 0 and WIDTH - 10 > ball.x > 0:
            ball.x += move_x
            ball.y += move_y
        
        if ball.y >= HEIGHT - 10:
            move_y = -ball_vel

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)

        ball_move()

        update()
```

Comment: You have to declare `move_y` as a global variable, otherwise the `ball_move()` function thinks it's a local variable.

Comment: I assume this is not the whole script as there is an `if` statement at the top that affects `move_y`. Please post the full traceback, and the lines it describes, if you haven't done so already.

Comment: @JohnGordon the variables `move_x` and `move_y` are redefined in the first few lines of the function; they're available to any inner functions inside `main`.

Comment: I badly copy and pasted my code but first two lines of code is just refer to the 2 lines in the ball_move() function. Using a global variable helped me a lot so thank you.

Comment: @OakenDuck they are available for _reading_ in the global scope, but not _assignment_.

Comment: They aren't global, either. This is where the `nonlocal` keyword comes in. However, *there is no good reason to nest the functions like this* in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the function

The code which causes the issue is in a function:

> ```py
> def ball_move():
>
>    if HEIGHT - 10 > ball.y > 0 and WIDTH - 10 > ball.x > 0:
>        ball.x += move_x
>        ball.y += move_y
>
>    if ball.y >= HEIGHT - 10:
>        move_y = -ball_vel
> ```

In the function `ball_move` is written to the variable `move_y`. This means the variable is declared inside the function's body and is a local variable (local in `ball_move`). Reading a variable before it is declared causes the error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'move_y' referenced before assignment

You have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) if you want to be interpret the variable as global variable. Actually there exist a variable with the same name in the function `main`. But since the same variable is to be set in `main`, it must also be declared there as global:

```py
def main():
    global run, move_x, move_y        # <---- ADD

    run = True
    ball_vel = 10
    move_x = ball_vel
    move_y = ball_vel

    def update():
        WINDOW.fill(black)
        ball.draw(WINDOW)
        player.draw(WINDOW)
        pygame.display.update()

    def ball_move():
        global move_x, move_y         # <---- ADD

        if HEIGHT - 10 > ball.y > 0 and WIDTH - 10 > ball.x > 0:
            ball.x += move_x
            ball.y += move_y
        if ball.y >= HEIGHT - 10:
            move_y = -ball_vel

    while run:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        ball_move()
        update()
```